# checkbox mal marcados en Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

Tengo una página en angular que me devuelve un listado de resultados de ejemplares de libros. Los filtros de búsqueda funcionan bien, los resultados están paginados, todo sin problemas.
Estos resultados tienen a su izquierda un checkbox, para poder marcar varios a la vez y poder, por ejemplo, borrarlos.

Lo que pasa, y es lo raro, es que cuando marcas un par de ellos y cambias de página, los checkbox pasan a la siguiente página, cuando no deberían...

Voy a poner unas capturas para explicarme mejor

La primera página, marco dos resultados: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cambio de página, y los checkbox siguen marcados, cuando no deberían estar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La página está montada con symfony, toma los datos de una query en un "action" y se los pasa a angular en el template

Para recuperar los datos se ejecuta una query, y el json se pasa de la siguiente forma:

```
$ejemplares = array();
foreach($data as $ejemplar_bd)
{
    $id_documento = $ejemplar_bd['id_registro'];

    $ejemplar = array();
    $ejemplar['id'] = $ejemplar_bd['id'];
    $ejemplar['idDoc'] = (int)$ejemplar_bd['id_registro'];
    $ejemplar['numregistro'] = (int)$ejemplar_bd['numregistro'];
    $ejemplar['codigo'] = $ejemplar_bd['codigoejemplar'];
    $ejemplar['estado'] = $ejemplar_bd['estado'];
    $ejemplar['signatura'] = $ejemplar_bd['signatura1']."-".$ejemplar_bd['signatura2']."-".$ejemplar_bd['signatura3'];
    $ejemplar['tipo'] =$ejemplar_bd['tipoejemplar'];
    $ejemplar['reservas']=$ejemplar_bd['reservas'];
    $ejemplar['Ubicacion']=$ubicaciones[$ejemplar_bd['id']];
    $ejemplar['Motivo']=$ejemplar_bd['motivo_expurgado'];
    $ejemplar['Editorial']=$data_editorial['valor'];
    $ejemplar['Imprimido']= $ejemplar_bd['imprimido'];
    $ejemplar = array_merge($ejemplar,$fondos[$id_documento][$ejemplar['id']]);

    $ejemplares[] = $ejemplar;

}

$this->json_data = json_encode($ejemplares);
```

Y se pinta en el template así:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar | filtroNumregistro:numregistro | filtroCodEjemplar:codEjemplar | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro  | orderBy:sort:reverse | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
        <td class="sf_admin_text sf_admin_list_td_nombre">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{ item.id }}" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.codigo }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.numregistro }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text sf_admin_list_td_titulo">
            <span><a ng-href="{{cambiarUrlTitulo(item.id)}}">{{ item.Titulo }}</a></span><br/>
            <span class="autorListEjemplar" ng-repeat="autor in item.Autor">{{autor}}{{$last ? '' : ' - '}}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.ISBN }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.Editorial }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.Ubicacion }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.signatura }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.tipo }}
        </td>
      </tr>
```

¿Qué podría estar pasando?
¿Por qué se mantienen los checkbox de una página a otra?

Gracias

Comment: cambia esta linea `<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{ item.id }}" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">` por `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">` aprovechando el comentario no es imprimido es impreso

Comment: Sí!!! Funciona! Mil millones de gracias!!

Comment: Y me temo que tanto imprimido como impreso están admitidos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debes cambiar la linea

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{ item.id }}" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
```

por

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
```

Si deseas saber cuales de tus items fueron marcados chequeados debes recorrer tu array simplemente puedes hacerlos con angular facilmente:
Suponiendo que tu arreglo esta en `$scope.data`

```
for(let i in $scope.data){
    console.log($scope.data[i].checked);
}
```

**¿Porque?**

Angular no funciona de la misma manera que solo HTML , el tiene librerias que modifica el DOM para hacer mas "facil" la vida del programador y esto a los que empiezan en este mundo cometen algunos errores comunes como por ejemplo el manejo de formularios.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en este caso no me hizo la vida más fácil y me confundió bastante. Sí, soy novato en angular ;)

Comment: Me temo que no entiendo eso, donde hay que poner ese bucle?

Comment: El bucle es si necesitas tener los valores por alguna razón es un ejemplo

Comment: Sí, de hecho, lo necesito, pero me refiero, donde tengo que implementar eso?

Comment: en cualquier parte o funcion de tu controller que visualiza esos datos